# How to configure unbound to forward local hostname resolution to my local DNS server?

Tags: domain-name-system, unbound

How can I configure unbound to forward local hostname resolution to my local DNS server (e.g., 192.168.1.1), i.e. for hostnames without any dot, such as "foo"?

Note that for all the other hostnames, a normal recursive resolution should be done. So, something like

```
forward-zone:
  name: "."
  forward-addr: 192.168.1.1
```

is not acceptable, because this forwards every request to the local DNS server.

**EDIT:** The DHCP server has very few options. In particular, it is not possible to add a domain.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me this is where default domain comes in. For instance, if you set your DHCP server to set the default domain of your systems to `whatever.lan`, you should then be able to set

```
forward-zone:
  name: ".whatever.lan"
  forward-addr: 192.168.1.1
```

Your undotted machine `pimpernel` would then publish itself, and get recorded in local DNS, as `pimpernel.whatever.lan`, and any other local machine looking for it should append that same domain as part of its lookup request. But normally the local address server at 192.168.1.1 would forward anything it can't understand... so I'm unsure why you'd need this, unless it was to eliminate the local DNS server's cache.

Comment: The DHCP server is provided by the FTTH router, and it is not possible to add a domain.

Comment: In that case it gets a little more difficult as you have to visit each machine and assign it a default domain (if we're talking Linux). In Windows, on the network connection Properties, TCP/IP v4 Properties or TCP/IP v6 Properties, Advanced TCP/IP settings, DNS tab you'll find the "DNS Suffix for this connection" box, that's the default domain. You'll also want to check "Register this connection's addresses in DNS" and "Use this connection's DNS suffix in DNS registration".

Comment: For the Linux machines, there is already a default domain (so that they have a fixed FQDN), but this is ignored by the DHCP server. Anyway, this is probably better like that in order to avoid inconsistencies, because there is no way to set a domain name for the Android devices.